# Android: How can I make this "&#2360;&#2350;&#2379;&#2360;&#2366;" appear as Hindi characters in my app?

Tags: android, encoding, hindi

I have these codes that are from a database.  They represent Devangari (Hindi) script:

```
&#2360;&#2350;&#2379;&#2360;&#2366;
```

I have a Hindi font installed on my phone.

How I get these codes to display as Hindi script in my Android app?

Comment: displayed where? Dialog? TextView? EditText? Notification? Toast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a TextView, try `.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml("&#2360;&#2350;&#2379;&#2360;&#2366;")`